# Comparing (ordering) rate and sample size

Tags: ratio, number-comparison

Consider some rate, i.e. fail rate where *f* is the number of fails and *n* is the number of attempts.

$$failrate = \frac{f}{n}$$

$$failrate = \frac{100}{100} = 1$$

$$failrate = \frac{99}{100} = .99$$

$$failrate = \frac{1}{1} = 1$$

If I were to sort on fail rate (descending) *1/1* would sort before *99/100*. The resulting sort order of the above would be *(1, 1, .99)*.

What would be a good method to influence the sort order such that number of attempts is also considered. My desired sort result is *(1, .99, 1)* because there were many more attempts (99 vs 1) and I consider this to be a better reflection of the fail result.

I would be helped if someone could point me to some methods or reading material on the above.

Comment: In order to sort them as a function of two variables, you need to join the two variables into a single auxiliary variable. In practice, I would just test out some simple functions of the form $a=a(f,n)$. Here $a$ is the auxiliary function.

Comment: A very simple example: The function $a(f,n) = f+n$ would return your desired order because $100 + 100 > 99 + 100 > 1 + 1$. But if you have more data and more values, you would have to consider what this type of function would give.

Comment: Depending on the software you're working with, you could also consider a "second sort", which means that if two entries get the same value in the first sort, then the second sort is looked at. In this case, your first sort can be as a function of either $f$ or $f/n$, and the second sort would be as a function of $n$.